# Get all possible combinations and sum the quantity

Tags: python

I'm trying to sum the sales quantities for all possible combinations of a predefined set of product options. Therefore i have created multiple option lists and a sales list. The sales list could also contain other products or "garbage" that I'm not interested in.
What would be the smartest way to do this?

Here is my try. It does kinda work but if the amount of combinations gets too large (like 1 to 300 millions) it either takes forever or crashes. Furthermore some options can be not populated (None entry in option a and b). I'm not quite sure how to check for that.

```py
# Check if all options of combination are in string
def check_code_in_string(combinations, string):
    for element in combinations:
        if element is None:
            return False
        element = element  # + r'(-|$)'
        if not re.search(re.escape(element), string):
            return False
    return True


# option lists
product_type = ['ProductA', 'ProductB', 'ProductC']
product_number = ['1234', '5678', '9012']
option_a = ['-A1', '-A2', '-A3', None]
option_b = ['-B1', '-B2', '-B3', None]

# sales list
sales = [['ProductA-1234-A1-B3', 25],
         ['ProductA-5678', 18],
         ['ProductC-9012-A3-B3', 28],
         ['ProductB-5678-A3-B2', 57],
         ['ProductA-9012-A1-B3', 22],
         ['ProductB-9012-A3-B3', 114],
         ['ProductB-1234-B2', 7],
         ['ProductA-5678', 3],
         ['ProductB-1234-B2', 15],
         ['ProductA-1234-A1-B3', 12],
         ['ProductA-9012-A1-B3', 62],
         ['ProductB-9012-A3-B3', 215]]

# generate list of all possible combinations
lst = [product_type, product_number, option_a, option_b]
combinations = itertools.product(*lst)

# add sales quantity as last column
tmp = []
for combination in combinations:
    tmp.append([combination[0], combination[1], combination[2], combination[3], 0])
combinations = tmp

# iterate over all products and all combinations and sum up the sales
for i, combination in enumerate(combinations):
    for product in sales:
        if check_code_in_string(combination[:-1], product[0]):
            combinations[i][4] = float(combinations[i][4]) + product[1]

# remove all combinations with 0 sales
tmp = []
for combination in combinations:
    if combination[4] > 0:
        tmp.append(combination)
reduced_combinations = tmp

print(*reduced_combinations, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Can you turn this problem on its head and avoid generating all the combinations? You don't care about anything that has zero sales. And you know all the product strings that have non-zero sales, because they're in the `sales` list? What if you wrote a function that converted (e.g. `ProductB-9012-A3-B3`) into its 4 components? Then you can get your totals just by iterating through `sales`. (I guess you probably also needs a filter that tells you if the product string is something that you don't care about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hoodlum & slothrop said you don't need to generate all the combinations. here is another approach.

```
sales = [['ProductA-1234-A1-B3', 25],
         ['ProductA-5678', 18],
         ['ProductC-9012-A3-B3', 28],
         ['ProductB-5678-A3-B2', 57],
         ['ProductA-9012-A1-B3', 22],
         ['ProductB-9012-A3-B3', 114],
         ['ProductB-1234-B2', 7],
         ['ProductA-5678', 3],
         ['ProductB-1234-B2', 15],
         ['ProductA-1234-A1-B3', 12],
         ['ProductA-9012-A1-B3', 62],
         ['ProductB-9012-A3-B3', 215],
         ['ProductZ-9012-A3-B3', 900]]


# option lists
product_type = ['ProductA', 'ProductB', 'ProductC']
product_number = ['1234', '5678', '9012']
option_a = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', None] #remove (-)
option_b = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', None]

option_list = [*product_type,*product_number,*option_a,*option_b]


def total_sales(sales):
    total = {}
    for sale in sales:
        product, quantity = sale
        product_options = product.split('-')
        if set(product_options).issubset(set(option_list)):
            if product in total.keys():
                total[product] += quantity
            else:
                total[product] = quantity

    return total


print(total_sales(sales))
```

Answer (score 1):

As slothrop said in the comments : avoid generating all the combinations. This will get unmanageably huge really fast.
Instead you might consider each component to see if it fits your requirements. A good use-case for the Python built-in function [`filter`].(https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)

A possible implementation would be as follows.
*NOTE* It's far from optimized (e.g: checking if `None` is contained in the options list at each filtering is not optimal). But it should be much faster than generating all the possible permutations.

```py
# option lists
product_type = ['ProductA', 'ProductB', 'ProductC']
product_number = ['1234', '5678', '9012']
option_a = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', None]  # NOTE : remove the dash (-) in the options
option_b = ['B1', 'B2', 'B3', None]

# sales list
sales = [['ProductA-1234-A1-B3', 25],
         ['ProductA-5678', 18],
         ['ProductC-9012-A3-B3', 28],
         ['ProductB-5678-A3-B2', 57],
         ['ProductA-9012-A1-B3', 22],
         ['ProductB-9012-A3-B3', 114],
         ['ProductB-1234-B2', 7],
         ['ProductA-5678', 3],
         ['ProductB-1234-B2', 15],
         ['ProductA-1234-A1-B3', 12],
         ['ProductA-9012-A1-B3', 62],
         ['ProductB-9012-A3-B3', 215]]


class MyFilter:
    def __init__(self, product_type, product_number, *options):
        self.product_type = product_type
        self.product_number = product_number
        self.options_lists = options

    def __call__(self, *val: tuple[str, int]) -> bool:
        '''return `True` if the product matches the filter values'''
        product_name, sales_value = val

        # NOTE : assumtion is that there are no other dashes in the string!!
        product, number, *options = product_name.split('-')

        # start by checking the simple stuff. immediately quit if it's not good
        if product not in self.product_type:
            return False
        if number not in self.product_number:
            return False

        i = 0  # counter variable
        for options_list in self.options_lists:

            # for each option, check if it is contained in the current `options_list`
            if i < len(options) and options[i] in options_list:
                # it's in the options list. great! let's go to the next one
                i += 1
                continue

            # if the option is not in the options list,
            # we need to check if it's OK for this option to be "not populated"
            elif None not in options_list:
                return False

        # great success, we passed all the tests
        return True


# create the filter object
my_filter = MyFilter(product_type, product_number, option_a, option_b)

# apply the filter object and sum
filtered_sales = filter(my_filter, sales)
total_sales = sum(sale for (prod, sale) in filtered_sales)

print(total_sales)
```